# seperation of variables difficult integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x'(t)=x(t)*(a-x(t)), x(0)=x_0$

I have to solve this ODE with seperation of variables.
But I have problems.

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=x(t)*(a-x(t)) \iff \underbrace{\int_{x_0}^{x(t)}\frac{1}{s(a-s)}ds}_{(*)}==\int_0^t1d\tau$

I can't solve $(*)$.
Anybody here who can help me?
Thanks.

Zitrone

Comment: Partial fractions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the ansatz
$\frac{1}{s(a-s)}=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{a-s}$ with real numbers $A$ and $B$ which means
partial fraction decomposition.